# Correlated brownian interpolation

Tags: matlab, conditional-probability, interpolation

I would like to generate conditional correlated random variables. I have a correlation matrix between normal variables, and these variables are modeled through SDEs.

What are the algorithms to generate such random values? One example I found is;
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/econ/interpolate.html

Comment: What software do you wish to use for this?

Comment: I can use any software. As I point out Matlab does this, but I would like to learn the numerical method behind this method; ex how to do Brownian bridge on multivariate distrubution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate correlated gaussian variables
by computing the Cholesky decomposition of the variance matrix
and multiplying independent gaussian variables with it.
There was a similar question on [Quant Stackexchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/how-to-simulate-correlated-assets-for-illustrating-portfolio-diversification/)
a few days ago.

To simulate the solution of a stochastic differential equation (SDE),
you can just discretize it, i.e., consider it as a difference equation (this is called the "Euler scheme") and use the correlated 
brownian motion you want.
In some cases, this is too imprecise,
but it is possible to derive
a second-order approximation of the SDE 
from Ito's formula (this is called the "Milstein scheme"; 
it is an analogue of the Runge-Kutta method).
If you are using R, this is implemented (for instance) 
in the `sde` package
and described in the accompanying [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387758380).

Comment: Yes I know with Cholesky you can simulate correlated random variables. Here the issues is after having a sample of N variable by length T samples, how can I interpolate/conditional sample between the already produced samples

Comment: If it is just a brownian motion, and not a general SDE,
you can multiply the sample you already have 
by the inverse of the Cholesky matrix:
this gives you a sample from N independent brownian motions.
You can then interpolate them separately 
(these are independent brownian bridges), 
and multiply the result by the Cholesky matrix.